# Finding a triangle ratio.

Tags: geometry

> In the triangle ABC, the point P is found on the side AB. AC = 6 cm, AP = 4 cm, AB = 9 cm. Calculate BC:CP.

For some reason, I cannot get this even though I tried for half an hour.

I got that, $BC/CP < 17/10 = 1.7$ by the triangle inequality. $AP/PB = 4/5$

But that does not help one but, I'm very stuck!

Comment: Variable angle at $A$ is implied here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\angle{BAC}=\theta$. Then, by [the law of cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines), 
$$\begin{align}BC:CP&=\sqrt{9^2+6^2-2\cdot 9\cdot 6\cos\theta}:\sqrt{4^2+6^2-2\cdot 4\cdot 6\cos\theta}\\&=\sqrt{9(13-12\cos\theta)}:\sqrt{4(13-12\cos\theta)}\\&=\color{red}{3:2}\end{align}$$

Comment: Damn, always on fire huh?

Comment: @mathlove You were ultra fast. Can you spot my error with the same speed?

Comment: $ AC= PA +PC $ and $ PC+ CB = PB $ so such a construction is impossible by triangle inequality !!

Comment: Please  sketch it on Geogebra..

Comment: @Narasimham: Maybe you think that $BC=3,CP=2$? We have $BC:CP=3:2$.

Comment: May be my assumption that angle at $A$ can be *uniquely*  solved is at fault. $ BAC $ is not a rigid triangle but a *mechanism*. It has an interesting connection to the Apollonius circle.

Comment: @Narasimham, the Apollonius circles are actually close to the method I used for my solution.

Comment: Did you get the Apollonius Circle then?

Answer (score 1):

The given problem cannot be solved.

If points $P,C,B$ are connected by an elastic rubber band varying angle at $A$ by hinging about $A$ indefinitely many solutions can exist.

EDIT 1/2

It turns out the problem has no $unique$ solution as I originally expected, but is a *locus.*

EDIT3

[image: Apollonius]

Sketched here what I had in mind when I said what I said about locus. It is not relevant to the problem or its solution. However allow me only to say in modest any understanding or context of what we are saying I believe is essential in mathematical considerations.

Comment: The problem asks us to find the ratio $\dfrac{BC}{PC}~.~$ Are the lengths of *either* one of the two segments *uniquely* determined ? **No !** But their *ratio* is, and *that's* what the problem is asking for..

Comment: The problem as given and and solutions as given by mathlove and Rajput are all correct, which incidentally I had also obtained . Mathematics is not computation alone. My comment is about *visualization of  all  possibilities* ., viz., $ BC = \lambda   bc, PC = \lambda pc $ and the Apollonius Circle locus which if you say is *outside* the range of proper answer, then  Hmm..The mathematician often thinks of uniqueness besides existence.

Comment: @Narasimham.  Sorry I am not verifying what you have written, but agree with the thought process. So neutralized the negative vote. Mathematics is not about rote computation as you have rightly pointed out.

Comment: Hoped the lateral thinking is n't irrelevant, many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Notice, let $BC=x$ & $CP=y$ now, applying cosine rule in $\triangle ABC$ $$\cos\angle BAC=\frac{AB^2+AC^2-BC^2}{2(AB)(AC)}=\frac{9^2+6^2-y^2}{2(9)(6)}=\frac{117-y^2}{108}\tag 1$$
similarly, applying cosine rule in $\triangle APC$
$$\cos\angle BAC=\frac{AP^2+AC^2-PC^2}{2(AP)(AC)}=\frac{4^2+6^2-x^2}{2(4)(6)}=\frac{52-x^2}{48}\tag 2$$
Equating (1) & (2), we get 
$$\frac{117-y^2}{108}=\frac{52-x^2}{48}$$ 
$$468-4y^2=468-9x^2$$

$$\frac{y^2}{x^2}=\frac{9}{4}\implies \frac{y}{x}=\frac{3}{2}$$
$$\color{red}{BC:CP=3:2}$$

Comment: $ AC= PA +PC $ and $ PC+ CB = PB $ so such a construction is impossible by triangle inequality !!

Comment: yes, construction is impossible but the ratio of $BC$ & $CP$ is constant for the given datas

Comment: I shall upload a picture, even if it does not matter for this post at all.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly enough, this problem can also be solved by treating the triangle as three points and knowing that $C$ must be $6$ units away from $A$. If you put $A$ at $(0,0)$ $P$ at $(4,0)$, and $B$ at $(9,0)$, $C$ must be somewhere on the circle $x^2 + y^2 = 36$.

If $C$ is on that same line at $(-6,0)$, $BC=15$ and $CP=10$.

If $C$ is on the line at $(6,0)$ instead, $BC=3$ and $CP=2$.

I will say that the Law of Cosines solution from MathLove is probably the way to go about this though.

Comment: I think this only works for $AP < AC < AB$ however.

Comment: Indeed, I like to see point $Q$ so that $ PQ =2 , QB= 3 $ the bisector of angles and the circle you mentioned actually  sketched.  And also hope for moderator's indulgence..

Comment: I'll sketch it tonight and upload it then.

Comment: I shall also upload what I am meaning, please comment.

Comment: My drawing looks like what you just uploaded actually. I apologize for not uploading last night. http://i.imgur.com/whj4AR0h.jpg

Comment: Fine, essentially it is the same.